# Why send addTarget Method have the : to work

Tags: ios, uibutton

Hoping someone can help me with why I should add a : to invoke the method.

Here is the viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.backgroundColor= [UIColor yellowColor];
//Add Button
CGRect buttonRect= CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 44);
UIButton *clickButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[clickButton setFrame: buttonRect];
[clickButton setTitle:@"Click Me" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[clickButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:clickButton];
[self buttonPressed:clickButton];
//Add UILabel
CGRect labelViewRect= CGRectMake(50, 30, 200, 44);
UILabel *labelview= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:labelViewRect];
[labelview setText:@"Hello welcome to my app!"];
//Clear the UIView button's background
[labelview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:labelview];
}
```

Here is the Button Pressed method

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
NSLog(@"This button was pressed");
self.view.alpha=((double)arc4random()/0x100000000);
}
```

When I remove the : from

```
    [clickButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

i.e. am changing this above line to something like this

```
 [clickButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

An exception is thrown:

> 2012-12-29 17:56:18.209 AlphaSchoolColor[11414:c07] -[com_skminfotekViewController buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde2f050
>   2012-12-29 17:56:18.210 AlphaSchoolColor[11414:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[com_skminfotekViewController buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde2f050'

Question to community is what is happening with that : and where are some more information I can learn about its importance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method has an arg. If you want to send action without the ":" then change your method.

```
-(void)buttonPressed{
}
```